# Check if randomly generated username is unique

Tags: php, mysql

I need to have a system where a random password and username are created for each new user.

As such, I need to make sure the username is unique.

However I cant figure out why the code below isn't working. It isn't a syntax issue. I just can't figure out where I have gone wrong logically.

anyway here is what I have tried:

```
    $Password= randomPassword();
    $Username = randomPassword();
    $UsernameCheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$Username."'");
    while (mysql_num_rows($UsernameCheckQuery ) >= 1) {
        $Username = randomPassword();
        $UsernameCheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$Username."'");
      }
```

I know this topic appears elsewhere on Stack Overflow and on the web. However every question I have seen has been using an `if` statement to check if the username is already used. In my case I cant see how an `if` statement would work as the `randomPassword` function could generated two username that already exist in a row.

Comment: for one you should probably use a do while loop. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I dont think it is. Please see me question about if statements

Comment: It is exactly a duplicate. Don't check if the username already exists, check if the attempt to insert the row failed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ahh that makes sense - Thanks
I believe this question is a duplicate 
how do i specify that

Comment: You click flag on the question. I have done it for you.

Comment: I don't thinks it's a dup. OP doesn't want to abort if id exists. He wants to keep trying until success.

Comment: Create a UNIQUE index to USERNAME , no duplication insert into datbase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
while (true) {
    $Username = randomPassword();
    $UsernameCheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$Username."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($UsernameCheckQuery ) < 1) {
       break;
    }
}
echo 'The generated username is '.$Username;
```

Comment: works perfectly just syntax error for `break;` and logic error `<`